# Spring-Boot REST - Required String parameter is not present

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

So, I'm trying to to a POST request to a local Spring MVC project, but every time I try, I keep getting 400: Bad Request, with the error specified in the title. Not sure why, because when I check what's being sent, it's correct.

Spring REST controller request

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
void addPet(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String photo, @RequestParam String status) {
    Pet pet = new Pet(name, photo, status);
    this.petRepo.save(pet);
}
```

AngularJS request sending the data

```
$http({
       method: "post",
       url: "http://localhost:8080/pet/add",
       data:{
           name: angular.element("#name")[0].value,
           photo: angular.element("#photo")[0].value,
           status: angular.element("#status")[0].value
       }
    }).success(function(data, status) {

        })
        .error(function(data, status) {
            alert("Error");
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
        });
```

front-end HTML that's calling the AngularJS function

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Pet Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="photo">Photo URL</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="photo">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="status">Status</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="status" placeholder="Something descriptive like 'Available' or 'Taken'">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="preview()">Preview</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The answer posted below is an improvement since it doesn't rely on doing DOM manipulation outside of directives (generally a bad thing) if you drop jQuery selectors don't work and really with how angular directives work you rarely need the selectors (can use querySelector() in most cases if you need it).  Also to note good to check your network panel request to see the payload (at the bottom) and response from the server, also good to test with POSTMan or curl to take angular or any particular front end out of the equation.

Comment: Open your browser network tab, what's sent in the request?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis 
name:"Pet"
photo:"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg"
status:"Available"

Comment: @shaunhusain Testing in postman gives me a successful request.

Comment: @BrandonHewlett hmm hmm hmm.... do you by chance have an external proxy program? (Charles web debugging proxy is what I've typically used, believe you can proxy postman requests with an extra extension or something as well) if you can get both XHR requests in the network tab you can right click and save the curl and then use diff to see what changed (probably some junk but something is different that's important) maybe a header or otherwise causing it not to parse the payload properly (a for alliteration).

Comment: @shaunhusain I do not have one, no

Comment: @shaunhusain Just noticed something, if it makes a difference. In postman, the information sent to the server is entered under Body >> form-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer. I followed SSH's answer above for the front-end, and for the backend, I changed the function to:

```
void addPet(@RequestBody Pet pet)
```

Answer (score 9):

You are using @RequestParam in the backend but in angular you are putting the values in the body of the request.

You have to use @RequestBody in the backend or adjust the frontend to put the values in url parameters.

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Pet Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="form.name" id="name">
   </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="photo">Photo URL</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="form.photo"  id="photo">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="status">Status</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="form.status"  id="status" placeholder="Something descriptive like 'Available' or 'Taken'">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="preview()">Preview</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="submit(form)">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in controller use this

```
 $scope.form = {"name":"","photo":"","status":""}
 $http({
   method: "post",
   url: "http://localhost:8080/pet/add",
   data:{
       name: $scope.form.name,
       photo: $scope.form.photo,
       status: $scope.form.status
   }
}).success(function(data, status) {

    })
    .error(function(data, status) {
        alert("Error");
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
});
```

Comment: What difference will any of this make? Please clarify your answer.

Comment: may be your data that send to server not match with RequestParam fields type.

Comment: Please edit that (or some version of that) into your answer.